# I can connect to my database using SQL Server 2005 but not SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, connection, ssms

I was able to connect to my database engine using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio, but now I cannot connect using the newer 2008 version.

Has anyone experienced the same problems? Is there a small feature to turn on that I am missing somewhere? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error are you specifically getting?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you do not provide any usefull informations, like error message, how you tried to connect (windows authentication/sql authentication), .... that's hard to come up with *the solution*.....

1) try to run SSMS as admin... if you can connect, then grant specific user with proper access

2) if you try to connect via TCIP/IP, try to run SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable TCP/IP protocol

3) if you need sql authentication, change the authentication on the server's properties.